# Django: Show only mandatory fields in forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm using Django and I have created several models in models.py. Some fields are optional and some fields are mandatory.

Is a there a way that a user can view only mandatory fields in forms?

I'm using `crispy forms` package to render my forms.  Now the user can see all the fields from the models.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

U can get all model's data (looking for blank=True ? ) by parsing from your model

```
MODELNAME._meta.get_fields_with_model()
```

or

```
 MODELNAME._meta.__dict__
```

run over fields and make alist of fields u wanna exclude from the form .
next - exclude fields

From the docs
[django proj](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/)

```
class PartialAuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        exclude = ['title']
```

or what ever is good for u